# "'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'Double'" error in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, cgfloat

I'm trying to cut an image into 9 pieces in Swift. I'm getting this error:

> **'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'Double'**

I get this error when I put `i` or `j` in the two variables.

Below is part of the code used for cutting the image.

```
for i in 1...3
    {
        for j in 1...3
        {
            var intWidth = ( i * (sizeOfImage.width/3.0))
            var fltHeight = ( j * (sizeOfImage.height/3.0))
        var portion = CGRectMake(intWidth,fltHeight, sizeOfImage.width/3.0, sizeOfImage.height/3.0);
            .
            .
      "Code goes on"
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift there is no implicit conversion of numeric data types, and you are mixing integers and floats.
You have to explicitly convert the indexes to `CGFloat`s:

```
var intWidth = ( CGFloat(i) * (sizeOfImage.width/3.0))
var fltHeight = ( CGFloat(j) * (sizeOfImage.height/3.0))
```

As often happening in swift, the error message is misleading - it says:

> 'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'Double'

whereas I'd expect:

> 'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'Int'

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-starter in Swift 5.5 (automatic conversion). We can pass `CGFloat` and `Double` interchangeably to functions that accept either of those types.